# How to compare a value "nan" from to_numeric in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, csv, type-conversion

I have a problem with the pandas lib... I use pandas.to_numeric to compare the column to a value, but, when the original value is not a "number similar", the pd.to_numeric transform the csv cell in a "nan" value, but i don't know how to compare this "nan" value in a "if"...
Basically, if the value of the cell is nan, i need to catch the cell in right position, like this:

```
    while counter < len(df): #df is my pandas Dataframe
    if df.values[counter][2].isnull(): #[2] is my column with "possible nan values, but not works!"
        if 0 <= df.values[counter][4] <= 100: #[4] is my column with "number values"
            df.values[counter][2] = df.values[counter][4]
            df.values[counter][1] = df.values[counter][3] #[3] Like column [4]
    counter += 1
```

Basically, the real reason i have to do that is because my CSV file sometimes get a "Shift to the right" in some lines!

Thanks in Advance!!

@Edit 1:

My dataset:

---

Time | ... | current | bt_disable | bt_cpy | bt_health | ...

---

2561456 | ... | 48945 | Normal | 20 | Good | ...

2589749 | ... | 41485 | Normal | 21 | Good | ...

2561456 | ... | 48945 | Normal | 22 | Good | ...

**2561986 | ... | 1 | 48515 | nan | 23 | ...**

**2569921 | ... | 1 | 49821 | nan | 24 | ...**

2561456 | ... | 43253 | 0 | 25 | Good | ...

---

The two lines in **Bold** have shifted to the right...
The "shift" thing is automatic, i don't have control...

*to_numeric lines:*

```
df[BCY] = pd.to_numeric(df[BCY], errors='coerce') #BCY and others is the name of column
df[BCN] = pd.to_numeric(df[BCN], errors='coerce')
df[BPD] = pd.to_numeric(df[BPD], errors='coerce')
df[BHT] = pd.to_numeric(df[BHT], errors='coerce')
```

You can see my original CSV file have columns in | ... | that i don't use, but, when i use to_numeric in BT_CPY column, and the line is shifted, the value *normal* transforms in a "nan", and what i need is verify this nan and if nan == true i need to catch the bt_health value and put on bt_cpy column!

Comment: can you show us your dataset?

Comment: @Shrey of course, give me a second!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I pretty didn't understood your question
but to compare a value with "NaN", use math.isnan()in if condition.
This works for me always :)